# Convert dataframe string/datetime column to parquet date

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, time, parquet

I have a Dataframe in which I have a string column 'exam_date' is in YYYYMMDD format. For example 20201130

I have a requirement where I have to convert this Dataframe to parquet and upload it however while uploading I want the schema type of the column to be DATE

The `java -jar parquet-tools.jar schema myfile.parquet` command should show the type as

```
optional int32 exam_date (DATE);
```

I have tried converting the column to DateTime type like this

```
final_calc_df['exam_date'] = pd.to_datetime(final_calc_df['exam_date'],format='%Y%m%d')
                                           .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

However, this gives me the output like

```
optional binary exam_date (STRING);
```

What should I do to get the desired output?

What I want is to keep data in YYYYMMDD format but instead of string/datetime/binary type I want it to be date type Date

```
optional int32 exam_date (DATE);
```

Comment: try to convert to UNIX time, with datatype int (no fractional days), see [parquet format: date](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#date)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you convert the column to datetime.date:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['20211011']})
from datetime import datetime
def to_date(s):
  return datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d').date()
df['a'] = df['a'].map(to_date)
```

or simpler but possibly less efficient:

```
df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.date
```

Comment: I think it would be simpler if you'd call `.dt.date()` on a pandas datetime column (not native Python datetime)

Comment: I think that assumes that the column is already a datetime pandas column.  From the OP it isn't quite clear but it seems like the values are strings?  I update the example to do pure pandas code (thanks for note) but I think this is less efficient since it requires going from String -> offset since unix epoch -> calendar date.  Parsing using native python date time should cut out the middle step I think.

Comment: @MicahKornfield I wish to maintain the YYYYMMDD format, doing dt.date changes the format, also pd.to_datetime(df['a'], format='%Y%m%d') does not mean it will change the format of the date. It means that it will accept the dates from df['a'] in the given format and then convert it in to datetime.

Comment: The underlying engine that writes to Parquet for Pandas is Arrow.  It isn't  clear what you mean by "maintain the format". If the data is strings it will always convert to bytes. If it is important for display purposes you can use the code above, save the string column separately and after writing to Parquet revert the column. If keeping it for  optimization then first converting to an [arrow Table](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.from_pandas) (which to_parquet would do anyway) and casting the column to timestamp the date might be more efficient.